# r - for each row, return colnames that matches a value

Tags: r, dataframe, match

dataframe

```
    rd2 <- data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 20), y = sample(1:100, 20), z
    sample(1:100, 20))

    # function I found in stackoverflow for finding the second largest value
    maxN <- function(x, N = 2){
      len <- length(x)
      if(N > len){
        warning('N greater than length(x).  Setting N = length(x)')
        N <- length(x)
      }
      sort(x,partial = len - N+1)[len - N+1]
    }

    # indexing values
    rd2[, "axis1n"] <- apply(rd2[1:3], 1, function (x) max(x))
    rd2[, "axis2n"] <- apply(rd2[1:3], 1, function (x) maxN(x))

    rd2
        x  y  z axis1n axis2n
    1  56 63 84     84     63
    2  50 45 13     50     45
    3  79 21 43     79     43
    4  33 46 33     46     33
    5  46 26 12     46     26
    6  55 47 11     55     47
    7  85 76 85     85     85
    8  43 56 48     56     48
    9  17 67 92     92     67
    10 37 43 59     59     43
    11 21 89 27     89     27
    12 57 44 25     57     44
    13 27 20 88     88     27
    14 63 62 44     63     62
    15 80 14 46     80     46
    16 88 54 54     88     54
    17 16 97 65     97     65
    18 48 83 77     83     77
    19 77 17 53     77     53
    20 47 64 70     70     64
```

Hello,

I  need to add two columns to this dataframe, where:

axis1:
for each row, column name of the column that matches value in axis1n (maximum value)

axis2:
for each row, column name of the column that matches value in axis2n (second largest)

Getting the column name of the maximum value is easy with max.col but I need a method that can be reproduced for many different indexing values, such as the second largest value or simply the list of numbers given..

Hope I am making sense.. Please help!

Thanks!!

Comment: so for row 1, axis1 would be "z" and axis2 would be "y"

Comment: I need to be able to do this by using any given integer/list of integers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not tested, but perhaps you could introduce another parameter to the existing function where you would control how "far back" from maximum the function reaches.

Also note that I have deleted the `N` - this is something which doesn't need to be controlled by the user. If you set `reachback = 0`, you will get maximum. `reachback = 1` will output second to maximum value and so on...

I have also disabled the truncation of former N - if you overreach, you get an error. Feel free to leave it as it is or change the `error` to `warning` and add `reachback <- len` line.

```
set.seed(357)
rd2 <- data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 20), y = sample(1:100, 20), z = sample(1:100, 20))

# function I found in stackoverflow for finding the second largest value
maxN <- function(x, reachback = 0){
  # reachback = 0 is maximum, 1 is second to last, 2 is third to last and so on...
  len <- length(x)
  if(reachback > len){
    error('You can not overreach the number of variables.')
  }
    names(sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)[1 + reachback])
}

# indexing values
# rd2[, "axis1n"] <- apply(rd2[1:3], 1, function (x) max(x))
rd2[, "axis_max"] <- apply(rd2[1:3], 1, function (x) maxN(x, reachback = 0))
rd2[, "axis_2nd"] <- apply(rd2[1:3], 1, function (x) maxN(x, reachback = 1))
rd2[, "axis_3rd"] <- apply(rd2[1:3], 1, function (x) maxN(x, reachback = 2))
rd2

    x  y  z axis_max axis_2nd axis_3rd
1  11 19 18        y        z        x
2   6 46  4        y        x        z
3  28 36 64        z        y        x
4  22  5 40        z        x        y
5  63 68 48        y        x        z
6  45 66 26        y        x        z
7  88 35 50        x        z        y
8  70 15 87        z        x        y
9  72 48  7        x        y        z
10 91 89 46        x        y        z
11 57 98 73        y        z        x
12 47 83 36        y        x        z
13 41 25 35        x        z        y
14 20 44 33        y        z        x
15 51 50 17        x        y        z
16 15 69  6        y        x        z
17 27 59  8        y        x        z
18 75 22 59        x        z        y
19 90 70 30        x        y        z
20 35 64 20        y        x        z
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the tip! Though I really need help on getting column names of the matching value on each row!! Any idea for that? :D

Comment: @user5813583 ah, just a second.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method using `order` on the column names.

```
# get the column names
cols <- names(rd2)

cbind(rd2,
      setNames(data.frame(t(apply(rd2, 1,
                                  function(i) cols[order(i, decreasing=TRUE)]))),
                     paste0("max", 1:3)))
```

which returns

```
    x  y  z max1 max2 max3
1  11 19 18    y    z    x
2   6 46  4    y    x    z
3  28 36 64    z    y    x
4  22  5 40    z    x    y
5  63 68 48    y    x    z
6  45 66 26    y    x    z
...
```

Here, `cols[order(i, decreasing=TRUE)]` returns the column names sorted from highest to lowest. `apply` applies this to each row in the data.frame. `t` transposes this and `data.frame` turns this into a data.frame, while `setNames` adds names to the data.frame. This is combined to the original data.frame with `cbind`.

You can change the number of columns listed by adding `[` to `order(i, decreasing=TRUE)` like `order(i, decreasing=TRUE)[1:2]` to get the top 2 column names. You can also alter the column names by changing `paste0("max", 1:3)` to your desired values.